# object recognition on mousePressed on it

Tags: p5.js

how i can recognize which object is selected by mousePressed on the object. I have make two objects textarea and div created by createElement() on p5js canvas.but when I mousePressed on textarea,it doesn't recognize it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing you can do is build different functions for them,

You can do something like this:

```
function setup() {
    var ta = createElement("textarea");
    var div = createElement("div");

    ta.mousePressed(forTextArea);
    div.mousePressed(forDiv);
}

function forTextArea() {
    //do something with text area
}

function forDiv() {
    //do something with div
}
```

[Click here for demo](https://alpha.editor.p5js.org/MasterYushi/sketches/rktXtyYxb)

[*mousePressed Reference*](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Element/mousePressed)

Comment: it is my requirment to draw textarea and div on runtime and on p5js canvas.when i clicks on textarea it does't works but on div it works.

Comment: This method will work, check the demo and click on the play button, then click on text area and div and you will see appropriate message in the console